# How to prevent Html.ActionLink to encode non-ASCII character in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, url-encoding

In my following code, when postSummary.SEOFriendlyTitleInURL contains Chinese characters, those characters will be encoded in the url.

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    postSummary.Title,
    "View",
    new
    {
        id = postSummary.Id,
        friendlyTitle = postSummary.SEOFriendlyTitleInURL
    })
```

Although that url will be shown as original characters in Google Chrome and Firefox, it is an encoded string in IE. I want to prevent the default encoding behavior of ActionLink method, because I can type directly in address bar those characters that are not encoded. So I think they are legal in URL.

I can simply construct the link manually, but it would be better to be generated for consistency:

```
<a href="/post/@postSummary.SEOFriendlyTitleInURL/@postSummary.Id">@postSummary.Title</a>
```

**Edit:**

My current solution: instead of prevent the framework from encoding just non-ASCII characters, I tell it to not encode any characters, by using Html.ActionLink combined with Server.UrlDecode method. In case there are some characters that do need to be percent-encoded, they could only appear in the "friendlyTitle" fragment. Because that fragment is only used for readability, I replace such characters with a dash character.

Such replaced characters including

- a list of reserved characters in URI. see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2
- single and double quote
- tab character

Still, non-ASCII characters should be percent-encoded at some point because they are not valid in URI, and it is better to be done when URL is generated. But by observing Fiddler when request a page through a URL that contains Chinese characters, it seems that the URL will be encoded automatically (maybe by web browser). For readability, I choose to let web browser do the encoding work.

Comment: Do not be fooled by what is displayed in the address bar; that is no reliable indicator of what is legal in a URL or not.

Comment: @Andrew If what I type in address bar can lead me to the page I want, that is enough. I would care even if they are illegal

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the browsers as far as what is being generated in your `<a>` tag; the only difference is in how the browser is displaying it. There's nothing to be altered here; `Html.ActionLink()` is correctly encoding/not encoding.

Comment: yes, the generated url is legal and works, but it is uneasy to be read. I include that title in url just for readability, otherwise the id value would be enough. I want someone seeing that url knows something about what is that page talking about when I am sharing the address in other sites. One other thing within my consideration is search engines might care what is in the url, but I am not sure.

Comment: when I said it is uneasy to be read, that means every single character would result in 3 bytes like "%E8%80%83", imaging how long the address could be for a post with title of just several characters